# Read Image Data from Raw12 file into a Buffer C++

Tags: c++, image-processing

I am kinda new in working on this kind of file. I want to read image date from a Raw12 into a buffer. After that, I'll convert 12-bit file to 8-bit. So, I stumbled upon a code, I want to know is there any better way to do this?

```
ifstream rawImage (fileName, ifstream::binary);
if (rawImage) {
    // Gets length of file.
    rawImage.seekg(0, rawImage.end);
    uint32_t length = rawImage.tellg();
    rawImage.seekg(0, rawImage.beg);

    // Allocates memory and stores the file info into a buffer.
    uint8_t * bufferImage = new uint8_t[length];
    rawImage.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(bufferImage), length);

    // Closes file.
    rawImage.close();

    // Array for storing the sensor information from the file.
    uint8_t * arrayImage = new uint8_t[4096*3072];
```

thanks for the help.

Edit:-

After reading comments, I re-wrote the code. Will this be fine? Is there anything missing?

```
      #include<iostream>
      #include<fstream>
      #include<sstream>
      #include<string.h>
      #include "LodePNG/lodepng.h"
      #include<cstdio>
      #include<cmath>
      #include<vector>
      #include <stdlib.h>

      using namespace std;

      const int BUFFERSIZE = 4096;   

      int main(int argc, char** argv)
     {
       if( argc != 2)
      {
 cout <<" Usage: display_image ImageToLoadAndDisplay" << endl;
 return -1;
}

  //Reading Raw12 file
   const char * fName = "filename.raw12";
   std::ifstream file(fName, std::ios::binary|std::ios::in);
   if (!file) { 
    printf("Error: could not open file %s\n", fName); return -1; }

   //Reading into Buffer

        uint32_t * buffer = new uint32_t [BUFFERSIZE];


      }
```

Comment: Ought to work. You might wonder why there is a need to check the size of the file when we apparently already know the size of the converted result. Or why we have to read the entire file into memory at once, instead of one slice at a time. But otherwise, kind of ok.

Comment: It depends how much memory you have to spare and how big your images are. If your images are large and you have limited memory, you may want to allocate your final array and read 3 bytes at a time, i.e. 24 bits, and then convert that to two 12-bit numbers and store them.

Comment: What are your doubts?
I would probably:
1. use a more appropriate name for the ifstream variable,
2. use the "ate" open mode (OR-ed with binary) and remove the seekg(0, end), but this is probably just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @BoPersson is this better now?

Comment: For hints and suggestions, you may consider moving your question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I think that will help. @roalz